# __SYSCALL vs __SC_COMP pre-processor macros in kernel source code`

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, system-calls

I am trying to understand the working of system calls and looking at how `syscall` numbers are defined and added to tables. In the [source//include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h?v=3.10) kernel source file I can see that after defining macros for system call numbers, those are being added to the system call table via `__SYSCALL` or `__SC_COMP` macros. What is the exact difference between the two ?

Comment: `__SC_COMP` is for system calls, for which you want to additionally have **compatibility** version. This is interface for 32-bit programs running with 64-bit kernel. Looks like given file is parsed twice: once for define normal syscalls, and once for define `compat` ones, if they are needed.